# Proof verification: Set of partial limits of a sequence is closed

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, proof-verification

I wanted to prove this claim but I'm not sure if this proof is okay. Please let me know what you think!

Let $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence, and let the set of its partial limits be $PL(a_n)=A=\{a|\exists a_{n_j}\rightarrow a\}$.

Let $a_0$ be an accumulation point of A, so, exists a sequence $\{x_n\}\subset A=PL(a_n)$ such that $x_n\rightarrow a_0$. But $\{x_n\}$ is a sequence of $a_n$'s accumulation points, *(Edit)* **so for any $\epsilon>0$ There are infinitely many terms of $a_n$ in $(x_j-\epsilon,x_j+\epsilon)$, for any $j\in \Bbb N$**.

Also, for any $\epsilon>0$,  exists $J\in \Bbb N$ such that for every $j\ge J$, $x_j$ is in the $\epsilon$ neighborhood of $a_0$, so and there is an infinite number of $a_n$'s terms in $(a_0-\epsilon, a_0+\epsilon)$.

It follows that *(Edit)* **for any $\epsilon$ exists $\epsilon '$ such that $(x_j-\epsilon', x_j+\epsilon')\subseteq(a_0-\epsilon,a_0+\epsilon)$ so there are infinitely many of $a_n$'s terms in the $\epsilon$ neighborhood of $a_0$**. This goes to show that $a_0$ is a limit point of $x_n$, so $a_0\in PL(a_n)$ so it is closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This pretty much correct.  One step you might explain a bit more carefully is when you say "there is an infinite number of $a_n$'s terms in $(a_0-\epsilon, a_0+\epsilon)$".  What you know is that there exists some $x_j\in (a_0-\epsilon,a_0+\epsilon)$.  You have also said earlier that there are infinitely many $a_n$ which are within any given $\epsilon$ of $x_j$.  However, you have to be a bit careful how you apply this, since you can't use the same $\epsilon$: you need your $a_n$'s to be contained in $(a_0-\epsilon,a_0+\epsilon)$, not in $(x_j-\epsilon,x_j+\epsilon)$.  What you can say is that since $x_j\in (a_0-\epsilon,a_0+\epsilon)$ there is some $\epsilon'>0$ such that $(x_j-\epsilon',x_j+\epsilon')\subseteq (a_0-\epsilon,a_0+\epsilon)$, and then since there are infinitely many $a_n$ in $(x_j-\epsilon',x_j+\epsilon')$ you get what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I totally see what you're saying. I'll edit the answer accordingly.