# prove that there's no sequence $a_n$ such that the set $[3,4)\cup [5,6]$ is the set of its partial limits

Tags: calculus

I supposed in the sake of contradiction that there is such a sequence and then I divided the problem into two cases, the first one is when $a_n$ converges or diverges to $\infty$ or $-\infty$ and then it's clear why it's wrong, but when $a_n$ diverges I didn't succeed to reach to anything

Comment: Isn’t set of partial limits always closed? See eg https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2390320/proof-verification-set-of-partial-limits-of-a-sequence-is-closed#:~:text=Let%20%7Ban%7D%E2%88%9En,xn%E2%86%92a0.

Comment: @SBF Exactly. I was to offer the hint in this case: suppose we have for each $k$ a subsequence converging to $4-\frac{1}{2^k}$, can't we then find a subsequence converging to $4$?

Comment: @ancientmathematician Post it then

Comment: @SBF I thought a hint would do. I'll wait a bit before typing up an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that there are subsequences converging to every point of $[3,4)$. Then we can construct a subsequence converging to $4$.

We recursively construct a strictly increasing function $f(n)$ such that $4-\frac{1}{2^n}\leqslant a_{f(n)}\leqslant 4+\frac{1}{2^n}$ for all $n\geqslant 1$, and then $a_{f(n)}\to 4$.

Let $f(0)=0$.

Now suppose that $f(0), f(1), \dots, f(n)$ are constructed.

As $4-\frac{1}{2^{n+2}}\in [3,4)$ we have a subsequence $a_{g(m)}$ converging to $4-\frac{1}{2^{n+2}}$, so that after some point $m_0$ all the $a_{g(m)}$ lie in $(4-\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}, 4+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}})$. Now define $f(n+1)$ to be $g(m)$, where $m$ is the least integer such that $m>m_0$ and $g(m)>f(n)$. Then we have  ensured that $f(n+1)>f(n)$ and that  $4-\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\leqslant a_{f(n+1)}\leqslant 4+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$ as required.